# How to activate my environment in linux automatically using .bashrc

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I would like to activate the environment that I created in Anaconda (myenv) automatically when linux server is opened. The myenv environment path is located in '/anaconda_env/personal/myenv'. I used the following command lines in .bashrc to automatically activate myenv. However, "base" environment is always activated instead of "myenv".

Can you help me correct my mistake in following command lines in order to automatically activate 'myenv' environment instead of 'base' environment?

Thanks.

```
export http_proxy=http://server-ip:port
export https_proxy=http://server-ip:port
export no_proxy="localhost,svc,node1"
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/miniconda/bin
alias envactivate="source activate /anaconda_env/personal/myenv"
alias spython="/anaconda_env/personal/myenv/bin/python"

## >>> conda initialize >>>
## !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/anaconda_env/miniconda/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/anaconda_env/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/anaconda_env/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/anaconda_env/miniconda/bin:$PATH"

    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following after last line in .bashrc

**conda activate /anaconda_env/personal/myenv**

Comment: Hello Gurdyal, if I want to activate /anaconda_env/personal/myenv automatically after creating screen in the crontab, may I know how can I write a command? Because after I add ```conda activate /anaconda_env/personal/myenv``` , when I start the linux server, myenv is activated and when I create a screen ```screen -S test```, myenv is activated but when I write ``` 21 11 * * * screen -dmS "acaa" && screen -S acaa -p 0 -X stuff "python ./test.py^M"```, it create  a screen but does not activate any environment.

Comment: Hi @Susan
Not sure I understand your Question .
Can you elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Hello @Gurdyal, I want to activate my own environment when I create a screen using detach mode. Moreover, as I want to create screen to run python script periodically, I use crontab. But I am not sure how to activate my own environment while creating a screen in crontab.

Answer (score 0):

```
export PATH="/miniconda/bin:${PATH}"
conda config --set auto_activate_base flase 
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/miniconda/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
conda activate <myenv>
```